# Android: Button being treated as tableLayout?

Tags: android, button, tablelayout, classcastexception

I'm writing an app for my android device that contains three buttons at the bottom of the screen. In my `onCreate` method I am setting three `Button` objects to their corresponding views using `findViewById()`. Here's the code I have written:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAdd = null;
    Button btnEdit = null;
    Button btnDelete = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        init(getApplicationContext());

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EventWriter.writeToFile(eventFile, getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    }

    ...

}
```

My XML looks like the following, with the button elements declared within a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/txtBtnDelete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/txtBtnAdd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/txtBtnEdit" />
```

When I try to run the application using the emulator in Eclipse, I get the following LogCat error at line #36 (`btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);`):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

I do have a `TableLayout` earlier in the code (located inside a `ScrollView`) but that does not contain the buttons:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/actvSearchEvent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/actvSearchEvent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scrollview_border" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I don't see where it's getting that I'm trying to cast the `TableLayout` to a `Button`. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a clean and clean build folder, then run the build again.

Comment: You actually beat me to it, I just cleaned the project and it worked just fine.  I was just about to post an answer myself.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that you are still pointing to the layout with the scroll view and the table layout. And there are no buttons in it.

You can easily fix this by pasting your buttons inside your table layout, e.g.

```
<TableLayout...>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/txtBtnDelete" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/txtBtnAdd" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/txtBtnEdit" />
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want the buttons inside the TableLayout, that's the whole point. Anyway, I ran a clean command on the project and everything worked fine. Not sure what caused it, but at least it's working again :)